# Importing Django authentication model in another project

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

ProjectA uses a custom authentication model CustomUser. ProjectB uses the default model, auth.User. One of the view classes in ProjectB needs to access some info in CustomUser in ProjectA. Upon importing the model I am getting the following error: "Manager isn't available. 'AppInProject1.CustomUser' has been swapped for 'auth.User'"
It seems that somehow the imported model conflicts with the authentication model in ProjectB.
AUTH_USER_MODEL has been properly specified in settings.py in each project.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!